# Javascript beginner help - array, while and for loop

Tags: javascript

I am taking a beginner javascript class. I am unable to figure what I am doing wrong in the assignment below. I am not fully understanding on how to put the pieces together. I have been using Firefox web console for debugging. However, I am stump on this one. Please give me feedback on how improve the code below. Your feedback is appreciated. =)

****The way the program should work:****

1. Prompt the user for a series of words (stored in a array)
2. It should include an option to exit the prompt
3. Finally, sort the list of words and join them together

---

```
var words = [];
while (true) {
    var word = prompt("Please enter a list of words or enter 'exit' to leave the prompt,"");
    if (word ==="exit") {
        break;
    }

    var total_words = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < words.length; index++);{
      total_words = words.sort[index];
}
document.write(words[index]);
```

Comment: Is the `""` at the end of your prompt just a typo in the question?

Comment: As a general hint: Try to get away from `prompt` and `document.write` as soon as you finish this class. Just don't ever really use it.

Comment: `words.sort[index]` won't ever work. You don't have to sort them each time, only once after you have all the words you need. Use `words.push(word)` to add the word to the array and sort it after the while loop done. I could give you working code, but that won't help you learn.

Comment: and look at the color coding from SO on this line: `var word = prompt("Please enter a list of words or enter 'exit' to leave the prompt,"");`.  You aren't closing the original string, so lines further down in your post are included within that string.  Everything gets messed up.  Change that to `var word = prompt("Please enter a list of words or enter 'exit' to leave the prompt","");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var words = new Array();
while (true) {
  var word = prompt("Please enter a list of words or enter 'exit' to leave the prompt","");
  if (word ==="exit") {
    break;
  }
  words.push(word);
}
words.sort();
document.write(words);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For whichever browser you're using, take a look at the error log. In Firefox, go to Web Developer -> Error Console. In IE, open Advanced options and uncheck "Disable Script Debugging", then take a look at the error that should appear when you load the page. In Chrome...I don't remember off the top of my head and don't have it on this computer.

You should see the following error messages:

1. Unterminated string literal - take a look at the syntax highlighting in what you posted. Notice the missing `"` in your `prompt` call.
2. Missing } in compound statement - your `for` loop has two errors: one is the `;` right afterward. This will not cause an actual runtime error, but it definitely won't achieve the results you're looking for. With a block or loop, you can run just a single line of code afterward and it will mark the end of the loop when it reaches a semicolon. In your case, you want just the curly braces. The second issue is that you have an open curly brace without a corresponding close.

Additionally, once you fix those two, the script will write "undefined" on the page. This is because no content is ever actually added to `words`. As mentioned in the comment by Joe Simmons, you need `words.push(word)` to add the word to the array.

I'm not sure what the `total_words` variable was for, since you never actually use it, but here's a start for what you need to do, ignoring that. I also removed the `for` loop since it was only used in conjunction with the `total_words` variable:

```
var words = [];
while (true) {
    var word = prompt("Please enter a list of words or enter 'exit' to leave the prompt", ""); //fix the quote issue here
    if (word ==="exit") {
        break;
    }
    words.push(word); //add entered word to array
}
words.sort(); //sort *after* the loop
document.write(words.join(",")); //this will write the words as a comma-separated list, as an example
```

So for that, if you enter in the prompts "dog", "cat", and "hippopotamus", the output will be:

```
cat,dog,hippopotamus
```

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for all the constructive feedback. I didn't even think of using the push() method. I've never used it before until now. I was using total_words to access the array. I knew what I was writing wasn't right. I just need to practice to get right.